# How to append text to specific php array value

Tags: php, arrays, append

I need to find certain keys in an array created by a MySQL query, once I have that key, I need to append some text to the value that the key is linked to

Ive figured out how to identify the key value with array_key_exists... I just need the code to 
append text to the associated value of the key

```
if(array_key_exists("note", $row_dailyNotes))
{
    // stuck here
    $row_dailyNotes(value) = $row_dailyNotes(value)."text to append"
}
```

Comment: You can't assign a value to a function. Fix your code first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$row_dailyNotes['note'] .= 'text to append';
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably what you're looking for is:

```
$array[$key] = $array[$key] . "text to append";
```

This uses the array syntax to look up a value or set a value in a PHP "array".

Example:

```
$array["something"] = $array["something"] . "blah blah";
```

There's also a short form using `.=` (the [string concatenating operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)):

```
$array[$key] .= "text to append;
```

Comment: isnt that appending to the key not the value?

Comment: @user1222646 - No, `$key .= "sometext"` would append to the key.

Comment: @user1222646: That is appending to the value, not the key. See http://php.net/Array